# Force SSL using FORCE_SSL_ADMIN

Tags: php, wp-config, ssl

I followed [this advice](https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/#using-a-reverse-proxy) from the official docs to force SSL:

```php
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Wordpress runs in a docker container. When it starts it says

> WARNING: The _SERVER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

And Wordpress' logs show this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Assignments can only happen to writable values in /var/www/html/wp-config.php

So `_SERVER` is the problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using docker-compose and the `WORDPRESS_EXTRA_CONFIG` as I was, when I stumbled across that error, the solution would be to use double-dollar-sign notation as described in a corresponding [issue in the docker-compose repo on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4189#issuecomment-274915631).

This additional environment variable is described in the "How to use this image" of [the official image documentation on hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress).

Your snippet in the context of a `docker-compose.yml` would be:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress:latest
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
      define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
      if (strpos($${_SERVER}['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
      $${_SERVER}['HTTPS']='on';
```

of course extended with an appropriate database container and corresponding environment variables for database and user name and passwords.

This will result in the environment variable `_SERVER` to only expand in the container. If you use a single dollar sign, docker-compose will try to populate the value of the specified environment variable from the surrounding context into the compose file as described in the [official compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files).